# Передача объекта из БД Realm на другой контроллер UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, uitabbar

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пытаюсь решить проблему передачи экземпляра класса на другой контроллер с использованием БД Realm.

У меня есть основной контроллер, который хранит объекты по модели следующие данные:

```swift
class Route: Object {
    @objc dynamic var routeImage: Data?
    @objc dynamic var routeName: String?
    @objc dynamic var numberOfPersons = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var dateOfDeparture: String?
    @objc dynamic var dateOfArrival: String?
    let placeToVisit = List<Place>()
    let person = List<Person>()
}
```

В том контроллере, в который мне нужно передать эти данные я создал

```swift
var currentRoute: Route!
```

В Storyboard я указал идентификатор "showDetail" от ячейки контроллера до UITabBar, а в основном контроллере, я создал метод:

```swift
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {return}

            let newPlaceVC = segue.destination as! InformationViewController
            newPlaceVC.currentRoute = routes[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
```

Но он не является валидным, приложение крашится по тапу на ячейку. полагаю это сработало бы если был не tabBar, а обычный table, view контроллеры. Я искал решения и все на что наткнулся, это реализация через singleton. Сейчас у меня масса вопросов, а действительно ли это будет правильным решением, т.к опять же люди говорят это нарушает "модульность" приложения и несет свои проблемы, да и тут же главный вопрос, а как это делается через синглтон? Что нужно учесть, с чего начать? Я новичок, очень прошу помощи.

Comment: Что вам мешает сохранить ваш currentRoute в БД, и после перехода в другой контроллер просто достать данные из базы?

Comment: Тогда как мне достать именно тот экземпляр, по которому было нажатие в tableVIew? У меня есть табличка на которой много ячеек хранящих объекты, я нажимаю одну из них и далее у меня tabBar с вьюшками, как передать именно тот объект?

Comment: Добавьте параметр в базу "row" (который будет сохранять индекс ячейки, как пример)